# MO in the Notices of the AMS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

On page 333 of the March 2010 issue, John Baez wrote that "MathOverflow has become a universal clearinghouse for math questions."

The March 2017 issue features an interview with Prof. Ken Ribet--the current president of the American Mathematical Society. At one point of the interview, Prof. Ribet expressed the following:

> It’s clear that one of the challenges for the AMS now is to continue to maintain its relevance in a context where young mathematicians are using technology to share and gather information with less of the formal structure that older mathematicians like myself are used to. People ask questions and get answers on MathOverflow...

I suppose these are not the only two instances in which MathOverflow was brought up in the pages of the Notices... If so, would you be so kind as to enter below those mentions of MO in the Notices that you recall?

EDIT. For some godforsaken reason, I was leaving out the "opinion" on MathOverflow authored by A. Geraschenko, S. Morrison, and R. Vakil which appeared in the June-July 2010 issue:

http://www.ams.org/notices/201006/rtx100600701p.pdf

Comment: This is probably rather naive approach, but you can probably find a few occurrences if you google for [mathoverflow notices site:ams.org](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathoverflow+notices+site:ams.org).

Comment: That's pretty much what I did.

Comment: And, of course, trying Google Scholar is also a rather natural thing to do in this context: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=mathoverflow+notices+site:ams.org or https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_q=mathoverflow&as_publication=Notices+of+the+AMS

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Opinion column ["Mathematical Community" in the March 2011 issue, by John Swallow](http://www.ams.org/notices/201103/rtx110300365p.pdf), asks, "Are mathematicians at the forefront of collaboration, with the advent of the Polymath Projects and Math Overflow?"

There's a passing mention in the January 2013 issue in ["When 7,000 Mathematicians Come to Boston" by Alexi Hoeft](http://www.ams.org/notices/201301/rnoti-p87.pdf) of a discussion session at the JMM "which turned out to be essentially an in-person MathOverflow thread...."

In the March 2013 issue, [Presidential Views: Interview with David Vogan, by Allyn Jackson](http://www.ams.org/notices/201303/rnoti-p336.pdf), MathOverflow comes up in the first paragraph.

In the January 2017 issue, [Morrison Awarded Australian Mathematical Society Medal](http://www.ams.org/publications/journals/notices/201701/rnoti-p52.pdf) says "Morrison is one of the founders of MathOverflow...."