# MathOverflow in the news

Tags: discussion

> What are some instances of MathOverflow being mentioned in the media?

Now that MathOverflow has recently had its tenth anniversary, I would be interested to learn of any mentions of it in the mass media. I'm interested in what the world outside MO, and indeed outside mathematics, has to say about MO, possibly prompted by its tenth anniversary, but I would also like to know of any such mentions in general over the last decade.

There is one article in the Notices of the American Mathematical Society [from 2010](https://www.ams.org/notices/201006/rtx100600701p.pdf), and some others mentioned in [this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3154/mo-in-the-notices-of-the-ams) and [Gerry Myerson's answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3154/mo-in-the-notices-of-the-ams/3155#3155) to it. When I search on the New York Times online for 'mathoverflow', [three articles are listed](https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=mathoverflow), but they don't seem to be accessible without a subscription. A similar search of a handful of other newspaper sites (Washington Post, Irish Times, Guardian, Neue Zürcher Zeitung, Le Monde, El País, Sydney Morning Herald) finds them remarkably quiet on the subject.

I see that the idea of having a meta question 'MathOverflow in the News', whose answers could list mentions in the media, was [raised by Joel David Hamkins](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/563/where-to-share-mathoverflow-success-stories/567#567) some years ago but I haven't been able to see it if it was ever followed up. If it was, perhaps somebody could provide a link to it; if not, perhaps this question could prompt such a list of media coverage.

Comment: The 3rd Times article concerns $2184=3^7-3=13^3-13$ and says, "Previously, a software engineer named Willie Wu had also noticed it and posted a question about it on MathOverflow. He found the same eight solutions, and conjectured that there are no more. One of his readers, a number theorist named Mike Bennett, pointed out that he had discussed this same question (and found the same answers) in this paper published in 2001." The MO reference is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158071/integer-solutions-of-xyn-y-xm-for-n-m

Comment: The paper from Notices is also mentioned in an answer to this question: [Papers, articles, books and other resources discussing MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4114). However, that post is in somewhat different direction - it's about academic papers, not about news.

Comment: This is probably a rather naive suggestion, but perhaps one could also check the results which you get when searching in [Google News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_News): https://news.google.com/search?q=mathoverflow